# How do I disable Online Videos in the Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, lenses

Recently, I discovered that, Unity lenses can access Internet to fetch information. Such as Video lens. But I want to disable that feature, since It is no use to me.

Can I disable access to Internet by Unity Video lens? If yes, How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a solution recently, though not very glorious enough, but it works.

#### Disable the file responsible for accessing Internet:

- First Open a terminal, go to "/usr/lib/unity-scope-video-remote" by the below command:

  ```
    cd /usr/lib/unity-scope-video-remote
  ```
- Disable the "unity-scope-video-remote" file there by this command below:

  ```
    sudo mv unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-video-remote.bak
  ```
- Logout and Login again, to see that the video lens is *unable* to access the Internet.

#### If you want to re-enable the feature:

- Just do the opposite of the above process, Go to "/usr/lib/unity-scope-video-remote" by the command:

  ```
    cd /usr/lib/unity-scope-video-remote
  ```
- Re-enable the file by following command:

  ```
    sudo mv unity-scope-video-remote.bak unity-scope-video-remote
  ```
- Logout and Login again, to see the effect

#### **13.04** (64-bit)

- In 13.04 the file is in a different directory.  Using bash's brace expansion, the command is:

  ```
    sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-lens-video/unity-scope-video-remote{,.bak}
  ```
- Re-enable the file by following command:

  ```
    sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-lens-video/unity-scope-video-remote{.bak,}
  ```
- As an alternative to logging in and out just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `unity --replace`

#### Will it disable the local video searching?

No, In this procedure, the local videos will always be visible. So, no worry !

Answer (score 6):

#### How to deactivate the Online Videos scope

This is as simple as removing the `unity-scope-video-remote` package, whose only function is to provide online video "recommendations" (see below) and searches. Open the terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`, and type:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove unity-scope-video-remote
```

Then logout once and log back in; online videos should be gone.

#### Right now, *Online Videos/Recommendations* has NO relation to you

- Looking at the source code for this package shows that it *eventually* intends to use the [**Zeitgeist**](http://zeitgeist-project.com/experience/) service database to come up with "recommendations"; *Zeitgeist* logs events, history, etc. and *also* enables the search-as-you-type in the dash feature. [Here's a more detailed article.](http://gnomejournal.org/article/70/an-introduction-to-gnome-zeitgeist)
- **But** as of Ubuntu 12.04, this isn't functional and the "recommendations" have *no relation* to you, your activities or your habits; they are simply sent from the Ubuntu video search server, either alphabetically or randomly:

  ```
  def update_recommendations(self):
      """Query the server for 'recommendations'.

      In v0, that means simply do an empty search.
  ```

Answer (score 3):

#### For 12.10

In 12.10, disabling online video results in Dash is made easier. Just search for Privacy in Dash and open this window.

[image]

Then turn off the option for *Include online search results*.

Comment: I still see requests going to videosearch.ubuntu.com ... every minute or so, even when I'm not using the Dash at all.