# How do I disable Online Videos in the Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to disable access to the Internet by Unity video lens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155331/is-there-a-way-to-disable-access-to-the-internet-by-unity-video-lens)

When I open the Unity Launcher and click on the last icon for videos, I get three lists: Recently seen, My videos, Online videos

Online videos is listing videos, that I consider highly inappropriate (for example a video trying to convince people with a live threatening disease to have faith instead of visiting a doctor).

- How is that list generated?
- How do I deactivate it?
- Why does it show those videos instead of videos I relate to? (I am the only user of this computer)

**Edit**: I am not referring to porn, but religion. I am fine that such context exists and is findable when searched. But I don't want that to **popup on my computer by itself**.

Comment: Related with this question? http://askubuntu.com/q/155331/61218